# Angular Component Not Rendering on Server Side

Tags: angular, typescript, server, frontend

I Have Made a Component Names  to display the activities in a destination:

[image]

SO the  component works when i run the ng-serve -o & ng-serve --prod (both times). But when I build the project by using the command ng build --prod, the component shows nothing

[image]

Here is the Screenshot of the console(if it helps).

[image]

Can SOmebody SUggests what's happening here.

Comment: please share code how you render the svg.

Comment: in your dist folder after build images are there ?  or you are using cdn for images ?

Answer (score 0):

**if you are directly opening index.html after build,  try using this command :-**

```
 ng build --prod --base-href="."
```

**better way will be to use http-server**

```
npm i -g http-server
```

**After building your project run**

```
http-server dist
```

Comment: I tried the command in the steps as you listed above but no success. The Section is showing empty.

Comment: can you provide a stack blitz?

Comment: and also tell after build how you are running the application?

Comment: I cant provide a stackblitz but i can tell you how i am running the application. I run the ng build --prod command and the upload the dist to the server using FIleZilla

Comment: can you see what url its forming for your svg file when you build it and using via filezilla, vs what url it foms while serving?

Comment: Use different environment file to decide which url to use when

Comment: The url its forming for svg file when i build it and using via filezilla is: `https://xxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/static/experiences/96/gridImg/1589964248195.jpg` and the url it forms when serving is: `https://xxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/static/experiences/96/gridImg/1589964248195.jpg` –

Comment: I am already doing it. I am using a enviornment.ts file & enviornment.prod.ts file to list out different url for different cases (i.e. dev & prod)